# Is there any point in storing am md5-encrypted password in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, md5

I'm not really a PHP programmer at all, mostly do javascript/design, but I am modifying some PHP code made by someone else, and I am wondering about the following:

Is there any point in storing a basic login password in md5() in a config.php file like the below?

```
define("USERNAME", "username");
define("PASSWORD", md5("password"));
```

I can understand that the constant will be stored encrypted, and when it is compared to a login attempt, it would be something like this:

```
if(PASSWORD == md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) ...
```

However, I am struggling to see that there is any benefit at all using encryption in this context, as its not sending the encrypted data, but just using it to compare a login attempt. Can someone tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: The only thing is that now if you echo ````$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ````  you can't read the exact password

Comment: `md5()` is not a encryption function. You use `md5()` to hash a string.

Comment: You are right. An intruder who can read the config file now knows the password. It would be better to store the result of `md5("password")` like `define("PASSWORD", "5f4d...");`. But even then [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/function.password-hash.php) would be the better alternative

Comment: @Szenis - `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` still contains the plaintext password, even after the comparison

Comment: @MarkBaker a ya ofcourse but the defined password does not

Comment: What you need to do is store your password with salted hashes. That is too large a (conceptual) subject to go into here and has been rehashed (pun intended) over the internet thousands of times. I suggest you Google for *encrypting passwords salted hash*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the code reveals the original password, you do not gain anything.

If you store only the hash inside the script, then somebody with access to the code cannot see the original password, and therefore could not login.

```
define("PASSWORD", 'db21e1fe1bf92b66ef2363d3c76c62d5');

if (PASSWORD = MD5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
```

MD5 is not a good choice to hash passwords though, you should use a precalculated BCrypt value, you can call the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to calculate it.

```
define("PASSWORD", '$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa');

if (password_verify($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], PASSWORD))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is just a super-basic login scheme for single-users with access to a config PHP file, and it seemed a bit "dumb" having having md5() pretending that it added some kind of security.

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one user, and his/her credentials are stored in php script, then yes, there is no reason to call md5() at all.
Except one specific case, when you could for some reasons do var_dump(PASSWORD) on the public accessible page.
But anyway, this is a wrong architecture from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

md5 is an encryption method. it encrypt the normal password and store in a data base in encrypted form. so that no one can  misuse  it. yes while comparing for login we need md5 both the side. password inserted must be made md5. if md5 password is stored in the database. 
hope you understand the logic.

Comment: it's a hash, not an encryption method. Hashes are one way only :)

Answer (score 0):

Well we use hashing to secure the app from possible vulnerability like(File Download vulnerability) even if you're web-app is secured and you're using a shared host they can use symbolic to see the php source file.

this is the time when he's looking to your password if your password is hashed (md5 ...etc) he will be trying to crack it (cracking = brute forcing the hash) or checking the hash databases.

your hash is protected (any hash type) only if you use a big string & don't use the online hashing tools (they'll sell your hash & the string to the hashing databases).

md5 is not recommended because of popularity.

there is no point of using

```
define("PASSWORD", md5("password"));
if(PASSWORD == md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){ echo 'validpass'; }
```

its like you're telling the attacker 'hey my password is the PASSWORD constant'

you should hash the password manually in php

```
<?php   
echo md5('YourPassHere').PHP_EOL; 
//a9903eab80299592904956c9f966f4c1 == YourPassHere 
?>
```

copy the hash & put it in (of course you have to do not use md5(); because you've already hashed the password)

```
define("PASSWORD", "a9903eab80299592904956c9f966f4c1");
```

and leave

```
if(PASSWORD == md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) { print 'valid pass';}
```